# Why isn't the Roomba deleting these questions?

Tags: support, automatic-deletion

I've been looking at [negatively-scored questions tagged Design](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bdesign%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+score%3A..-1&mixed=0). Many of the questions I see should have been deleted by the Community user, going by the criteria in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Let's take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447245/javascript-facade-method-grouping) for example. It is 908 days old (which is greater than 30). It is not locked. At the time of this post, it had a score of -1 (which is <= -1). It has no answers.

As far as I can tell, it meets all of the Roomba criteria, which is run daily. So why does it still exist?

(If the meta effect kills this question, there are plenty more just like it behind the first link in the post.)

Comment: It only got downvoted recently, 11 hours ago, probably because of that burnination.  Other questions in that list have upvoted answers.

Comment: On a tangential note.. [This userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why) can help you determine whether a question will be roomba'ed or not and why..